# iOS undefined linker ld error

Tags: ios, xcode

I wrote a simple function, passes the compiler but not the linker.

Any idea why?

```
- (BOOL) connectedToWifi
{

    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    // Get the dictionary containing the captive network infomation
    CFDictionaryRef captiveNtwrkDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));

    NSLog(@"Information of the network we're connected to: %@", captiveNtwrkDict);

    NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*) captiveNtwrkDict;
    NSString* ssid = [dict objectForKey:@"SSID"];

    if ([ssid rangeOfString:@"WXYZ"].location == NSNotFound || ssid == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CNCopySupportedInterfaces", referenced from:
      -[miApp_funcs connectedToWifi] in miApp_funcs.o
  "_CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      -[miApp_funcs connectedToWifi] in miApp_funcs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a required library or framework, try adding the SystemConfiguration framework to your target.

Comment: Newbie here, how do I do this with the latest Xcode on lion?

Comment: In the side bar click on your project -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> + -> and choose SystemConfiguration framework

Answer (score 4):

Following are steps-

1) Click project in Navigator area

2) Select 'TARGETS' tab

3) Click on 'Build Phases'

4) Select 'Link Binary With Libraries'

5) Then you can see '+' button at the bottom in the area.
 You can now add the SystemConfiguration framework that you want.

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to link to, and `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>`, to have access to the Captive Network (CN) classes and functions.